# "{Pay / Pay for} the expenses"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, ellipsis

I have a question about the usage of "*pay*" and "*pay for*":

> 1. He ***paid*** the expense.
> 2. He ***paid for*** the expenses.

Could both be the same?  This [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/pay) seems to say "*pay*" and "*pay for*" are the same.

Comment: A very similar question is here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44401/pay-for-the-library-card-vs-pay-without-for-the-library-card/44402#44402

Answer (score 3):

They are both basically the same sentence but there is a minor nuance between them.

1. He paid the expense 
   This focuses on the fact that the expense, like a bill, has been paid.
2. He paid for the expense
   This could mean that he paid it, or that he paid it on behalf of another. The focus here is on the subject he doing the paying in order to clear the expense.

Like I said, this is merely a nuance- and frankly depending on the inflection of voice, either sentence could shift the meaning back to the subject or the verb. But minus any voicing, I would expect the emphasis to be as above.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *pay* is both, *transitive* and *intransitive*. OALD gives examples of both.

> pay (for something) -*to give somebody money for work, goods, services, etc* AS IN "I'll pay for the tickets." 
>  ***AND*** 
>  pay something -  *to pay cash*

Thus to answer, it's okay using either of them.