# 'Pay $100 To Agent' or 'Pay Agent $100'

Tags: prepositions, word-order, transitivity

I have a question about the usage of "*pay*":

> 1. He ***paid*** the agent ***$100***.
> 2. He ***paid $100 to*** the agent.

Is the second pattern nonstandard? I don't seem to be able to find it in dictionaries.

Comment: The second pattern is totally standard, and quite common.    Also see this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44401/pay-for-the-library-card-vs-pay-without-for-the-library-card/44402#44402

Comment: Please stop acting as though anything not found in a dictionary is ["nonstandard"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6362+dictionaries). Dictionaries do not provide samples of every possible usage of a word or phrase.

Comment: @J.R. I'm afraid old bean that that is the fault of commenters and Mods  who keep telling everyone to look stuff up in dictionaries, even when that is blatantly inappropriate :(

Comment: @Araucaria I guess we need a canonical post, maybe titled "How to use dictionaries (the right way)", on our site. :)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, both are standard. For when to use which, I would suggest that in both sentences mild emphasis is placed on the last part—so in

> He paid the agent $100.

one could read it to be emphasizing the amount of money paid, while

> He paid $100 to the agent.

could be understood to emphasize that it's to the agent that the money was paid.

Comment: Quite right! I't good to see an answer that explains that the *END* of the sentence has the emphasis and not the beginning! :-)

Comment: +1 for the mention of [theme and rheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic%E2%80%93comment) (0:

Comment: Do you think that the indirect object pattern for "*pay*" ( *he paid the agent $100* ) is more common than the direct object pattern ( *he paid $100 to the agent* )?

Comment: @meatie: yes, I do.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. He paid ***the agent*** $100.
> 2. He paid $100 ***to the agent***.

This is a normal pattern for verbs like

- give,
  lend,
  offer,
  pass,
  pay,
  post,
  read,
  sell,
  send,
  show,
  promise,
  tell

These verbs all take two Objects. One Object is the thing that is being given. The other Object is the person or thing who receives it. The thing that is given is called the *DIRECT OBJECT*. The person receiving it is the *INDIRECT OBJECT*. The normal phrase order in  English is to put the Indirect Object first, and the Direct Object second:

- I posted **my mum** a letter.
- I showed **my teacher** my essay.
- They sold **me** an elephant.

However sometimes we want to move the Indirect Object to the end of the sentence. When we do this we need to put the Direct Object first. With verbs like *GIVE*, we need to use the preposition *to* before the Indirect Object when it comes second:

- I posted a letter **to my mum**.
- I showed my essay **to my teacher**.
- They sold an elephant **to me**.

Some verbs that take Indirect Objects use the preposition *for* when the Direct Object comes first. They don't use the preposition *to*. Here are some of the verbs that take *for*:

- book,
  buy,
  get,
  cook,
  keep
  bring,
  make,
  pour,
  save,
  find,

Here are some example sentences with the Indirect Object first:

- I bought **my mum** some flowers.
- I kept **you** a copy.
- They poured **me** a glass of wine.

Here are some examples with the Direct Object first:

- I bought some flowers **for my mum**.
- I kept a copy **for you**.
- They poured a glass of wine **for me**.

*Hope this is helpful!*

[**Note** When the Indirect Object comes second, it is not *really* an object of the verb any more. Instead it is part of a Preposition Phrase. It is the Preposition Phrase that is the complement of the verb]

**Ref**: I got my list of verbs from [this British Council website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/double-object-verbs)

Comment: In dictionaries definitely have the "*give something to somebody*" === "*give somebody something*" equivalence.  But the "***pay money*** *to somebody*" === "***pay*** *somebody* ***money***" equivalence could not be found.

Comment: @meatie Yes. If you're lucky you might get some good grammar advice from a dictionary, but more often not. You're right to ask the question here:) Dictionaries are *NOT* generally the right places to look for grammar info ... Unfortunately, it isn't always easy to track down the grammar info you need - so a good teacher, or other friends or colleagues are often a better place to start if you can't find what you need in a grammar book. Which, I think, is why this site exists! :-)

Comment: Do you think that the indirect object pattern for "*pay*" is more common than the direct object pattern?

Comment: @meatie If you mean IO first, DO second, then yes. This is the standard pattern and is much, much more common. But as Mathieu says below, what you use depends on what you're trying to emphasise :)

Answer (score 0):

Both are same but as I said in your [other question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49179/pay-or-pay-for-expense) (quite similar?), it depends whether you want to use the verb 'pay' as a transitive or intransitive.

> He paid the agent .... (verb taking direct object) 
>  He paid ....**to** the agent... (verb not taking direct object)

As we see, the verb 'pay' is both -transitive and intransitive.